# How to make a nav item conditionally rendred in sidebar menu of CoreUI in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

TL;DR: How to make a nav item conditionally rendred in sidebar menu of CoreUI?

So i have this nav menu from [CoreUI](https://coreui.io/react/) template. I created a login nav item, clicking on it will direct me to login page to authenticate.

1. When you are authenticated: Menu Item will be turned into "**Log Out**", clicking on it will direct you to **Home page**.
2. When you are **not** authenticated: Menu Item will be "**Login**", clicking on it will direct you to **login page**.

_nav.js:

```
const _nav = [
//...
  {
    component: CNavItem,
    name: 'Login',
    to: '/login',
    icon: <LoginIcon />,
  },
]
```

AppSidebar.js:

```
import navigation from '../_nav'
const AppSidebar = () => {
  return (
    <CSidebar
    >
      <CSidebarNav>
        <SimpleBar>
          <AppSidebarNav items={navigation} />
        </SimpleBar>
      </CSidebarNav>
      />
    </CSidebar>
  )
```

[image: CoreUi ReactJS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your navigation config to a function that takes whether the user is authenticated as an argument and figures out what the login/logout part of the navigation should be:

```
const getNavConfig = (isAuthenticated) => [
//...
  {
    component: CNavItem,
    name: isAuthenticated ? 'logout' : 'Login',
    to: isAuthenticated ? '/home' : '/login',
    icon: isAuthenticated ? <LogoutIcon /> : <LoginIcon />,
  },
]
```

Just call it as a function in your `AppSidebar` component and pass the user's authentication status:

```
import navigation from '../_nav'
const AppSidebar = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = <the way you get your auth status>;

  return (
    <CSidebar
    >
      <CSidebarNav>
        <SimpleBar>
          <AppSidebarNav items={navigation(isAuthenticated)} />
        </SimpleBar>
      </CSidebarNav>
      />
    </CSidebar>
  )
```

Comment: i got error `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _nav__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.default) is not a function` when i changed `items={navigation(isAuthenticated)}` This error appoints to this line.

Comment: Did you change your navigation config to a function? `const getNavConfig = (isAuthenticated) => [...]`

Comment: Thanks, this fix it, i forgot to do that. Please edit your code :)